# Any way to put custom configuration or settings for a community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-community

is There any way we could put some custom setting on a community?

Like we some special variables (e.g. `use_email_to_login`, `include_passwords_on_registration`) which allow a site admin to configure through community builder.

We want to store this configuration at the backend and read it when a registration method has been invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a custom object, or a List Custom Setting to handle this.  More info here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_customsettings.htm

You've asked a couple of questions today that make me think a read over the Communities documentation would be very helpful. I think it will give you a much better understanding of what tools are available to you.  Take a look:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_intro.htm